# how to make mysql queries in php run quicker

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am running queries on a table that has thousands of rows:

```
$sql="select * from call_history where extension_number = '0536*002' and flow = 'in' and DATE(initiated) = '".date("Y-m-d")."' ";
```

and its taking forever to return results.

The SQL itself is

```
 select * 
   from call_history 
  where extension_number = '0536*002'
    and flow = 'in' 
    and DATE(initiated) = 'dateFromYourPHPcode'
```

is there any way to make it run faster? should i put the where `DATE(initiated) = '".date("Y-m-d")."'` before the `extension_number` where clause?

or should i select all rows where `DATE(initiated) = '".date("Y-m-d")."'` and put that in a while loop then run all my other queries `(where extension_number = ...)` whthin the while loop?

Comment: Databases 101: Analyse the SQL query by using EXPLAIN, and learn to index your data tables

Comment: can you show us the table structure?

Comment: here is a screen shot: http://postimg.org/image/ukfq9q785/

Comment: A screenshot? No thanks. Give us proper DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1) Replace `SELECT *` by the only fields you want.

2) Add indexing on the table fields you want as output.

3) Avoid running queries in loops. This causes multiple requests to SQL server.

4) Fetch all the data at once.

5) Apply `LIMIT` tag as and when required. Don't select all the records.

6) Fire two different queries: one for counting total number of records and other for fetching number of records per page (e.g. 10, 20, 50, etc...)

7) If applicable, create Database Views and get data from them instead of tables.
Thanks

Comment: what are indexes for on columns that you don't select by? Indexes should be on columns you sort by or filter with.

Answer (score 1):

The order of clauses under `WHERE` is irrelevant to optimization.

Pro-tip, also suggested by somebody else: Never use `SELECT *` in a query in a program
unless you have a good reason to do so. "I don't feel like writing out the names of the columns I need" isn't a good reason. Always enumerate the columns you need.  MySQL and other database systems can often optimize things in surprising ways when the list of data columns you need is available.

Your query contains this selection criterion.

```
AND DATE(initiated) = 'dateFromYourPHPcode'
```

Notice that this search criterion takes the form

```
FUNCTION(column) = value
```

This form of search defeats the use of any index on that column. Your `initiated` column has a `TIMESTAMP` data type.  Try this instead:

```
 AND initiated >= 'dateFromYourPHPcode'
 AND initiated <  'dateFromYourPHPcode' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This will find all the `initiated` items in the particular day. And, because it doesn't use a function on the column value it can use an index range scan to do that, which performs well.  It may, or may not, also help without an index. It's worth a try.

I suspect your ideal index for this particular search would created by

```
 ALTER TABLE call_history 
   ADD INDEX flowExtInit (flow, extension_number, initiated)
```

You should ask the administrator of the database to add this index if your query needs good performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add index to your table. This way MySql will fetch faster. I have not tested but command should be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `call_history ` ADD INDEX `callhistory` (`extension_number`,`flow`,`extension_number`,`DATE(initiated)`);
```